# fullCalendar ignoreTimezone doesn't seems to work

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I am using [full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/ignoreTimezone/) and i think i m doing something wrong. As i set the property `ignoreTimezone:` "true", but it doesn't seems to work, it always displays the time according to +5:30(local Timezone), when i set the time (by converting in to another timezone using PHP), always displays according to +530

> allDay: false
>   end: "Thu, 18 Jul 2013 17:00:00 +0100"
>   id: 5
>   ignoreTimezone: true
>   start: "Thu, 18 Jul 2013 15:00:00 +0100"
>   title: "test 2nd"

As here, time shows "15:00:00-17:00:00", but in calendar it displays somthing this "19:30:00-21:30:00" i.e adding  with +5:30, instead i set the ignoreTimezone to true.

Any idea

Comment: @Manisha are you testing it on your local machine or on server?

Comment: u r not adding comma in between parameters

Comment: @KumariManisha Try by changing the timezone of your system and time and check. is it adding the +5:30 or not. Let me know after that I will tell. why this happens.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ yeah, its still adding +5:30

Comment: @KumariManisha May be there is issue in full calender js. try by using the other version of this. well Manisha my name is Gaurav.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ hey i changed the timezone back to my local timezone, and after reloading its showing the correct time, according to changed   timezone(+1:00). But when i changed the timezone again like in +3:00, then still the problem persists. Any idea??

Comment: @KumariManisha I am help less without code. But I can guide you to resolve the problem.

Comment: Hello Gaurav, Have you any idea why this happening??How??

Comment: Manisha ji, DO you have firebug install on your browser?

Comment: For me it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The option you are using is only available in version 1 of fullcalendar. Check if you are using version 1 or 2. If not sure about the version, you can check by just hitting $.fullCalendar in your console and you will get the version you are using.

Solution (if version 2):

As per version 2 of fullcalendar the option `ignoreTimezone` is deprecated as stated [here](http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/).

As `ignoreTimezone` was an event property, now you need to set fullcalendar property as

`timezone: false, //ignores the time zone`

Other possible values you can check [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/).

A working Demo by the official [website](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.3.1/demos/timezones.html).

> Note : It's recommended to check the deprecated list of options if you
>   are using newer fullcalendar version, as few other options have been
>   removed in the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

if you want set any specify time zone you can try this code..

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();